# Delay when calculating a players movement direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to determine the direction of a transform. I originally tried to do this by tracking the rigidbody.velocity but that property seems unreliable so I am having to calculate the direction manually. The yellow line draws fine and it does point in the wrong direction however it appears to be delayed

I am calling the following method in my update method:

```
    void DetermineMovementDirection()
    {
        currentLoc = (transform.position - prevLoc) / Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 t = (prevLoc + currentLoc).normalized;

        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + t * 5, Color.yellow);
    }
```

I would expect the yellow line to always point in the direction the player was moving rather than have a long delay. How can I fix this?

[image]

As requested the movement function:

```
    void Update()
    {
        float inputZ = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float inputX = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (movementAllowed)
            if (inputZ != 0 || inputX != 0)
            {
                transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, Mathf.Atan2(inputZ, inputX) * 180 / Mathf.PI, 0);
                transform.Translate(moveSpeed * inputZ * Time.deltaTime, 0f, moveSpeed * inputX * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            }
    }
```

And I am simply updating at the end of the update method:

```
prevLoc = transform.position;
```

Comment: Can you show how you are updating transform.position, and prevLoc?

Comment: @aresCaelum have added those examples for you :-)

Comment: Seems to me all you want if the forward direction of the player correct? You could just use the transform's forward property. Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.forward+ t * 5, Color.yellow);

Comment: Nope not the forward direction. The direction the player is actually moving. It is very common for a player to face a different way to what they are moving IE when jumping or falling and turning or alternatively if a player got shot by a grenade etc

Comment: @leoQuint Transform the forward depends on the orientation of the character... side stepping is not the direction the player is moving... Jamesla is there a reason you cannot just do `moveDirection = (transform.position - prevLoc).normalized;`